# Magento2 ElasticSearch product attribute weight based on value

Tags: magento2, product-attribute, search, elasticsearch

If there is a way to set product attribute weight depending on it's value?

F.e. we have 2 attributes to search: **name**(weight=10) and **description**(weight=1)
So in search results we'll have first results with search query in **name** and then other results with query in **description**.

The actual result we want to have:

1. Display first results with search query in **name** where product type is **simple**
2. Then display results with search query in **name** where product type is **virtual**
3. And then all other results mixed whatever.